# Development Roadmap Design and Consensus

Tags: development, research

Who was involved in the design and development choosing goals for the [Monero roadmap](https://getmonero.org/design-goals/)?

Once goals are identified, what procedures are in place to determine their level of priority?

Does the Monero Research Lab spend time vetting the conceptual viability of most major goals before significant developers hours are spent codifying them?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Monero Design and Development goals roadmap was produced by the [Monero Core Team](https://getmonero.org/knowledge-base/people)

The Core Team is an integral part of Monero Research Lab so cooperation is ongoing. For simple tasks Monero developers may act independently without requesting significant academic review. However, for more important and [cryptographically complicated tasks](https://lab.getmonero.org/pubs/MRL-0005.pdf) research is undertaken before coding begins. As issues are discovered during development, prior research is [updated](https://shnoe.files.wordpress.com/2016/03/mrl-0008_april28.pdf). Monero Core Developers are given access to ongoing MRL research [before it is completed of received peer review](https://github.com/monero-project/research-lab/commit/60a63a3b5d3f50afd504a76193925f0a132b7bb4#diff-27aeaa37167ee780b3c47339b2682fa9R534)

> This research bulletin has not undergone peer review, and reflects only the results of internal investigation.

One of the goals of sharing research while still in progress is to reduce the amount of time wasted pursuing objectives with critical flaws. Although significant cooperation exists, priority levels for certain tasks change over time based on the individual skill sets and interests of each developer/researcher.